# Flutter - remove a firebase document onTap()

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I have a ListView, filled with Firebase collection as chat messages.

When the user long press a ListTile (an item on the list), I show a BottomSheet.

When the user clicks the `Delete` button on the BottomSheet, the document should be removed. I'm unable to find a way to remove the selected document after tapping the "Delete" button.

The listview widget:

```
return ListView.builder(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    reverse: true,
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
    var message = snapshot.data.documents[index]["content"];
    var from = snapshot.data.documents[index]["idFrom"];
    return new ListTile(
        leading: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            child: new Image.network(
                "http://res.cloudinary.com/kennyy/image/upload/v1531317427/avatar_z1rc6f.png")),
        title: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(child: new Text(message))
        ]
        ),
        subtitle: new Text(from),
        onLongPress: () {
        showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                    child: new Wrap(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new ListTile(
                        leading: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                        title: new Text('Delete'),
                        onTap: () =>
                                          // Remove the tapped document here - how?
                                          print(snapshot.data.documents[index]["id"])
                                          Firestore.instance.collection("chats").document("ROOM_1")
                                          .collection("messages").document(snapshot.data.documents[index]["id"])
                                          .delete();
                                      )
                        )
                    ]
                    )
                );
            });
        }
    );
});
```

I need to find a way to remove the document in the `onTap()` method. not sure why, but even when I do:

```
 onTap: () => {
     // Remove the tapped document here - how?
     const id = snapshot.data.documents[index]["id"];
 },
```

the IDE retruns an error `Expected an identifier`

Comment: Try to remove the fat arrow `=>` on the onTap.

Comment: You cannot combine arrow with {} in dart compared to other languages you should try something like this onTap:() => snapshot.data.documents[index]["id"]

Comment: I updated the code, i'm still unable to remove a document, I get `Too many positional arguments` error. not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To delete a document, we can use the `runTransaction` method of the `Firestore.instance` and use the `delete` method of the `Transaction` class.

```
await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
    await myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data.documents[index].reference);
});
```

instead of

```
Firestore.instance.collection("chats").document("ROOM_1")  
    .collection("messages").document(snapshot.data.documents[index]["id"])
    .delete();
```

Here is the look of my dummy database before the deletion of `doc1` document:

[image]

After deleting `doc1`:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

If you know document id, You can delete easily.

```
  Future<void> rejectJob(String jobId){
    return _db.collection('jobs').document(jobId).delete();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2021:

Add the following code to your button's `onPressed` method.

```dart
final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
collection 
    .doc('some_id') // <-- Doc ID to be deleted. 
    .delete() // <-- Delete
    .then((_) => print('Deleted'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Delete failed: $error'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`.delete()` method will only remove the document fields but will not remove the nested collections in the document.

Use `runTransactions()` method to delete the document completely without leaving any data behind.

```
FireBaseFirestore.instance.runTransactions((transaction) async => 
await transaction.delete(DocumentReference));
```

So, use `runTransactions()` instead of `delete()` method.

Answer (score 3):

for simple and quick method  try this (especially if you use login/signup)

```
 Future deleteData(String id) async{
try {
  await  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("collection_name")
      .doc(id)
      .delete();
}catch (e){
  return false;
}
```

}

then under the delete button you can pass the deleteData function

```
onPressed:() {
                 deleteData(collection_name.id);
                 Navigator.pop(context);
                }, //delete
```